# Regular expression in javascript trouble with hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions and am having trouble setting one up. What I want is to allow only alphabets, numbers, commas, periods and hyphens. This is what I got:

```
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/;
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to include the hyphen. Please assist.

Comment: `var letters = /^[-a-zA-Z0-9,. ]+$/;`

Comment: By hyphens, do you mean only the regular dash (`-`), or other hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the minus where it won't be interpreted as a range:

```
var letters = /^[-a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/;
```

You can also use backslash to specify that it's a literal character:

```
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-. ]*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\,. ]+$/;
```